# Parsing a JSON string in node js?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I am trying to send a JSON string and parse it in my server side in node js.
I want to extract specific values like title but for some reason I get undefined when I try to parse it.

This is what I tried so far.

Home.ejs

```
 $.each(item, function(key, value)
             {
                 var s = JSON.stringify(value);
                 s = s.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,'');
                 info.push(s);
             });
             console.log("info",info);

            if (response.status == 'ok') {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '/home',
                    data: JSON.stringify(info),
                    success: function (data) {


                    },
                    error: function (data) {
                        console.log('error');
                        console.log(data)
                    }
                });
            }
```

This is what it prints out in the console.
info

```
(20) ["{"title":"Trump ends self-made crisis","pubDate":"…tweet-restricted-super-169.jpg"},"categories":[]}", "{"title":"Intel chiefs: Trump suggested we refute …-mueller-split-4-super-169.jpg"},"categories":[]}", "{"title":"New details emerge in US destroyer colli…ald-damaged-0617-super-169.jpg"},"categories":[]}", "{"title":"Former US government worker charged with…dana-boente-0510-super-169.jpg"},"categories":[]}", "{"title":"Sniper hits ISIS target from over 2 mile…110754-isis-flag-super-169.png"},"categories":[]}", "{"title":"Grenfell Tower blaze: Other London high-…london-fire-0614-super-169.jpg"},"categories":[]}", "{"title":"Prime Minister May offer: EU citizens ca…2344-theresa-may-super-169.jpg"},"categories":[]}", "{"title":"Ousted South Korean president's confidan…outh-korea-court-super-169.jpg"},"categories":[]}", "{"title":"Why neither North Korea nor the United S…k-in-photos-0421-super-169.jpg"},"categories":[]}", "{"title":"Warmbier funeral: 2,500 celebrate kid wh…ier-funeral-0622-super-169.jpg"},"categories":[]}", "{"title":"US, Japan missile interception test fail…issile-launch-02-super-169.jpg"},"categories":[]}", "{"title":"US officials: North Korea tested rocket …ek-in-photo-0519-super-169.jpg"},"categories":[]}", "{"title":"Zuckerberg: Why Facebook's mission chang…-interview-color-super-169.jpg"},"categories":[]}", "{"title":"Fitness model dies after freak kitchen a…burger-instagram-super-169.jpg"},"categories":[]}", "{"title":"Tropical Storm Cindy brings rain, wind t…ig-tbkl-00001316-super-169.jpg"},"categories":[]}", "{"title":"Taliban claim car bomb that killed 30","…an-car-bomb-0622-super-169.jpg"},"categories":[]}", "{"title":"The images Saudi Arabia doesn't want you…war-malnutrition-super-169.jpg"},"categories":[]}", "{"title":"Fact Check: Has Trump created 33,000 min…ig-alee-00003930-super-169.jpg"},"categories":[]}", "{"title":"What do young Indians think of Donald Tr…trump-modi-split-super-169.jpg"},"categories":[]}", "{"title":"Obama blasts Republican health care bill…5-obama-montreal-super-169.jpg"},"categories":[]}"]
0
:
"{"title":"Trump ends self-made crisis","pubDate":"2017-06-22 22:36:00","link":"http://www.cnn.com/2017/06/22/politics/trump-comey-tapes-recordings-white-house/index.html","guid":"http://www.cnn.com/2017/06/22/politics/trump-comey-tapes-recordings-white-house/index.html","author":"","thumbnail":"","description":"President Donald Trump finally, grudgingly, had no choice but to come clean.","content":"President Donald Trump finally, grudgingly, had no choice but to come clean.","enclosure":{"link":"http://i2.cdn.turner.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/170622175804-trump-tweet-restricted-super-169.jpg"},"categories":[]}"
1
:
"{"title":"Intel chiefs: Trump suggested we refute Russia collusion","pubDate":"2017-06-22 10:47:14","link":"http://www.cnn.com/collections/intel-intl/","guid":"http://www.cnn.com/collections/intel-intl/","author":"","thumbnail":"","description":"","content":"","enclosure":{"link":"http://i2.cdn.turner.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/170622120332-trump-mueller-split-4-super-169.jpg"},"categories":[]}"
2
:
"{"title":"New details emerge in US destroyer collision investigation","pubDate":"2017-06-22 23:31:38","link":"http://www.cnn.com/2017/06/22/politics/uss-fitzgerald-investigation-update/index.html","guid":"http://www.cnn.com/2017/06/22/politics/uss-fitzgerald-investigation-update/index.html","author":"","thumbnail":"","description":"Five of the seven Navy sailors who died aboard the USS Fitzgerald when it collided with a cargo ship off the east coast of Japan may have been almost instantly \"incapacitated\" and died quickly, according to a very preliminary Navy analysis, a defense official told CNN.","content":"Five of the seven Navy sailors who died aboard the USS Fitzgerald when it collided with a cargo ship off the east coast of Japan may have been almost instantly \"incapacitated\" and died quickly, according to a very preliminary Navy analysis, a defense official told CNN.","enclosure":{"link":"http://i2.cdn.turner.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/170617081911-07-uss-fitzgerald-damaged-0617-super-169.jpg"},"categories":[]}"
3
:
"{"title":"Former US government worker charged with giving top-secret info to China","pubDate":"2017-06-22 23:13:14","link":"http://www.cnn.com/2017/06/22/politics/top-secret-information-china/index.html","guid":"http://www.cnn.com/2017/06/22/politics/top-secret-information-china/index.html","author":"","thumbnail":"","description":"The Justice Department announced Thursday that it had arrested and charged a former US government employee for sharing top-secret information with a Chinese government agent.","content":"The Justice Department announced Thursday that it had arrested and charged a former US government employee for sharing top-secret information with a Chinese government agent.","enclosure":{"link":"http://i2.cdn.turner.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/170510133509-dana-boente-0510-super-169.jpg"},"categories":[]}"
4
:
"{"title":"Sniper hits ISIS target from over 2 miles away","pubDate":"2017-06-23 00:54:32","link":"http://www.cnn.com/2017/06/22/politics/canadian-sniper-record-shot-isis/index.html","guid":"http://www.cnn.com/2017/06/22/politics/canadian-sniper-record-shot-isis/index.html","author":"","thumbnail":"","description":"A Canadian special operations sniper successfully hit an ISIS fighter from a record-breaking distance of more than two miles away while assisting Iraqi forces in the push to retake Mosul, according to Canadian Special Operations Command.","content":"A Canadian special operations sniper successfully hit an ISIS fighter from a record-breaking distance of more than two miles away while assisting Iraqi forces in the push to retake Mosul, according to Canadian Special Operations Command.","enclosure":{"link":"http://i2.cdn.turner.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/160618110754-isis-flag-super-169.png"},"categories":[]}"
5
:
"{"title":"Grenfell Tower blaze: Other London high-rises 'combustible'","pubDate":"2017-06-23 02:40:44","link":"http://www.cnn.com/2017/06/22/europe/grenfell-tower-fire-theresa-may/index.html","guid":"http://www.cnn.com/2017/06/22/europe/grenfell-tower-fire-theresa-may/index.html","author":"","thumbnail":"","description":"Initial tests on cladding in a number of tower blocks in London have come back as combustible, British Prime Minister Theresa May told the House of Commons Thursday during a statement about last week's fatal Grenfell Tower blaze.","content":"Initial tests on cladding in a number of tower blocks in London have come back as combustible, British Prime Minister Theresa May told the House of Commons Thursday during a statement about last week's fatal Grenfell Tower blaze.","enclosure":{"link":"http://i2.cdn.turner.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/170614142852-45-london-fire-0614-super-169.jpg"},"categories":[]}"
6
:
"{"title":"Prime Minister May offer: EU citizens can stay in UK","pubDate":"2017-06-23 02:06:22","link":"http://www.cnn.com/2017/06/22/europe/theresa-may-brexit-rights/index.html","guid":"http://www.cnn.com/2017/06/22/europe/theresa-may-brexit-rights/index.html","author":"","thumbnail":"","description":"In a Brexit divorce deal offering, British Prime Minister Theresa May on Thursday said European Union citizens would be allowed to stay in the United Kingdom after the country leaves the EU.","content":"In a Brexit divorce deal offering, British Prime Minister Theresa May on Thursday said European Union citizens would be allowed to stay in the United Kingdom after the country leaves the EU.","enclosure":{"link":"http://i2.cdn.turner.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/170620152344-theresa-may-super-169.jpg"},"categories":[]}"
7
:
"{"title":"Ousted South Korean president's confidante sentenced to 3 years","pubDate":"2017-06-23 05:53:19","link":"http://www.cnn.com/2017/06/22/asia/south-korea-choi-soon-sil/index.html","guid":"http://www.cnn.com/2017/06/22/asia/south-korea-choi-soon-sil/index.html","author":"","thumbnail":"","description":"The confidante of former South Korean President Park Geun-hye has been sentenced to three years in prison for soliciting favors for her daughter, a press officer from the Seoul Central District Court told CNN Friday.","content":"The confidante of former South Korean President Park Geun-hye has been sentenced to three years in prison for soliciting favors for her daughter, a press officer from the Seoul Central District Court told CNN Friday.","enclosure":{"link":"http://i2.cdn.turner.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/161219150546-01-choi-soon-sil-south-korea-court-super-169.jpg"},"categories":[]}"
8
:
"{"title":"Why neither North Korea nor the United States want all-out war","pubDate":"2017-06-23 05:50:20","link":"http://www.cnn.com/2017/06/22/asia/north-korea-war-devastation/index.html","guid":"http://www.cnn.com/2017/06/22/asia/north-korea-war-devastation/index.html","author":"","thumbnail":"","description":"It's been a tense six months on the Korean Peninsula and many North Korea watchers believe the situation is dangerous.","content":"It's been a tense six months on the Korean Peninsula and many North Korea watchers believe the situation is dangerous.","enclosure":{"link":"http://i2.cdn.turner.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/170420182131-05-week-in-photos-0421-super-169.jpg"},"categories":[]}"
9
:
"{"title":"Warmbier funeral: 2,500 celebrate kid who would've 'set the world on fire'","pubDate":"2017-06-22 16:55:31","link":"http://www.cnn.com/collections/intl-warmbier-funeral/","guid":"http://www.cnn.com/collections/intl-warmbier-funeral/","author":"","thumbnail":"","description":"","content":"","enclosure":{"link":"http://i2.cdn.turner.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/170622152959-08-otto-warmbier-funeral-0622-super-169.jpg"},"categories":[]}"
10
:
"{"title":"US, Japan missile interception test fails","pubDate":"2017-06-23 03:05:10","link":"http://www.cnn.com/2017/06/22/politics/us-missile-intercept-test-fails/index.html","guid":"http://www.cnn.com/2017/06/22/politics/us-missile-intercept-test-fails/index.html","author":"","thumbnail":"","description":"A US and Japanese missile test conducted in Hawaii missed its target, but both militaries stopped short of calling it a failure.","content":"A US and Japanese missile test conducted in Hawaii missed its target, but both militaries stopped short of calling it a failure.","enclosure":{"link":"http://i2.cdn.turner.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/170206111347-standard-missile-launch-02-super-169.jpg"},"categories":[]}"
11
:
"{"title":"US officials: North Korea tested rocket engine","pubDate":"2017-06-22 23:31:27","link":"http://www.cnn.com/videos/world/2017/06/22/north-korea-tests-rocket-todd-dnt-tsr.cnn","guid":"http://www.cnn.com/videos/world/2017/06/22/north-korea-tests-rocket-todd-dnt-tsr.cnn","author":"","thumbnail":"","description":"Tensions between the US and North Korea continue to rise after North Korea tested a rocket engine, according to US officials. CNN's Brian Todd reports.","content":"Tensions between the US and North Korea continue to rise after North Korea tested a rocket engine, according to US officials. CNN's Brian Todd reports.","enclosure":{"link":"http://i2.cdn.turner.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/170518180155-09-week-in-photo-0519-super-169.jpg"},"categories":[]}"
12
:
"{"title":"Zuckerberg: Why Facebook's mission changed","pubDate":"2017-06-22 20:06:19","link":"http://money.cnn.com/2017/06/22/technology/facebook-zuckerberg-interview/index.html","guid":"http://money.cnn.com/2017/06/22/technology/facebook-zuckerberg-interview/index.html","author":"","thumbnail":"","description":"","content":"","enclosure":{"link":"http://i2.cdn.turner.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/170622131016-02-zuckerberg-interview-color-super-169.jpg"},"categories":[]}"
13
:
"{"title":"Fitness model dies after freak kitchen accident, family says","pubDate":"2017-06-22 19:15:18","link":"http://www.cnn.com/2017/06/22/world/rebecca-burger-whipped-cream-instagram-fitness-model-death-trnd/index.html","guid":"http://www.cnn.com/2017/06/22/world/rebecca-burger-whipped-cream-instagram-fitness-model-death-trnd/index.html","author":"","thumbnail":"","description":"A popular social media fitness personality died after what can only be described as a freak accident involving a whipped cream canister.","content":"A popular social media fitness personality died after what can only be described as a freak accident involving a whipped cream canister.","enclosure":{"link":"http://i2.cdn.turner.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/170622112522-0622-rebecca-burger-instagram-super-169.jpg"},"categories":[]}"
14
:
"{"title":"Tropical Storm Cindy brings rain, wind to Gulf Coast","pubDate":"2017-06-22 22:24:14","link":"http://www.cnn.com/videos/us/2017/06/22/tropical-storm-cindy-orig-tbkl.cnn","guid":"http://www.cnn.com/videos/us/2017/06/22/tropical-storm-cindy-orig-tbkl.cnn","author":"","thumbnail":"","description":"Six million people are under tornado watch in Louisiana, Mississippi and Alabama.","content":"Six million people are under tornado watch in Louisiana, Mississippi and Alabama.","enclosure":{"link":"http://i2.cdn.turner.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/170622181943-tropical-storm-cindy-orig-tbkl-00001316-super-169.jpg"},"categories":[]}"
15
:
"{"title":"Taliban claim car bomb that killed 30","pubDate":"2017-06-22 14:28:56","link":"http://www.cnn.com/2017/06/22/asia/afghanistan-car-bomb/index.html","guid":"http://www.cnn.com/2017/06/22/asia/afghanistan-car-bomb/index.html","author":"","thumbnail":"","description":"At least 30 people were killed Thursday in a car bomb attack outside a bank in Lashkar Gah, the capital of Afghanistan's southern Helmand province, officials said.","content":"At least 30 people were killed Thursday in a car bomb attack outside a bank in Lashkar Gah, the capital of Afghanistan's southern Helmand province, officials said.","enclosure":{"link":"http://i2.cdn.turner.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/170622071724-01-afghanistan-car-bomb-0622-super-169.jpg"},"categories":[]}"
16
:
"{"title":"The images Saudi Arabia doesn't want you to see","pubDate":"2017-06-22 16:26:56","link":"http://www.cnn.com/2017/06/21/middleeast/yemen-malnutrition-cholera-crisis-images/index.html","guid":"http://www.cnn.com/2017/06/21/middleeast/yemen-malnutrition-cholera-crisis-images/index.html","author":"","thumbnail":"","description":"Batool Ali is six years old, though you would never guess that from her huge, haunted eyes and emaciated frame. Ribs jutting out over her distended belly, Batool weighs less than 16 kilograms (35 pounds). She is one of nearly half a million children in Yemen suffering from severe malnutrition.","content":"Batool Ali is six years old, though you would never guess that from her huge, haunted eyes and emaciated frame. Ribs jutting out over her distended belly, Batool weighs less than 16 kilograms (35 pounds). She is one of nearly half a million children in Yemen suffering from severe malnutrition.","enclosure":{"link":"http://i2.cdn.turner.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/170619144015-12-yemen-civil-war-malnutrition-super-169.jpg"},"categories":[]}"
17
:
"{"title":"Fact Check: Has Trump created 33,000 mining jobs?","pubDate":"2017-06-22 23:59:36","link":"http://www.cnn.com/videos/politics/2017/06/22/fact-check-trump-mining-orig-alee.cnn","guid":"http://www.cnn.com/videos/politics/2017/06/22/fact-check-trump-mining-orig-alee.cnn","author":"","thumbnail":"","description":"CNN's Jake Tapper, in partnership with FactCheck.org, checks a Trump claim that the President added 33,000 mining jobs since his inauguration.","content":"CNN's Jake Tapper, in partnership with FactCheck.org, checks a Trump claim that the President added 33,000 mining jobs since his inauguration.","enclosure":{"link":"http://i2.cdn.turner.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/170622195811-fact-check-trump-mining-orig-alee-00003930-super-169.jpg"},"categories":[]}"
18
:
"{"title":"What do young Indians think of Donald Trump?","pubDate":"2017-06-23 05:02:14","link":"http://www.cnn.com/2017/06/22/asia/young-indians-trump/index.html","guid":"http://www.cnn.com/2017/06/22/asia/young-indians-trump/index.html","author":"","thumbnail":"","description":"Indian Prime Minister Narendra Modi is set to meet US President Donald Trump for the first time on Monday.","content":"Indian Prime Minister Narendra Modi is set to meet US President Donald Trump for the first time on Monday.","enclosure":{"link":"http://i2.cdn.turner.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/170125123753-trump-modi-split-super-169.jpg"},"categories":[]}"
19
:
"{"title":"Obama blasts Republican health care bill","pubDate":"2017-06-23 02:11:50","link":"http://www.cnn.com/2017/06/22/politics/barack-obama-health-care-bill-reaction/index.html","guid":"http://www.cnn.com/2017/06/22/politics/barack-obama-health-care-bill-reaction/index.html","author":"","thumbnail":"","description":"President Barack Obama on Thursday spoke out against a proposed GOP Senate bill that dismantles the Affordable Care Act, also known as Obamacare.","content":"President Barack Obama on Thursday spoke out against a proposed GOP Senate bill that dismantles the Affordable Care Act, also known as Obamacare.","enclosure":{"link":"http://i2.cdn.turner.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/170606215725-obama-montreal-super-169.jpg"},"categories":[]}"
```

server.js

```
app.post("/home",function(req,res)
{

    var data = (req.body);



    console.log("name",data);

    var news_title = [];
    var news_link =[];
    var news_date =[];
    /*for(var i in req.body){

        var item = req.body.items[i];
        //console.log(item);

    }*/
    //console.log("name",name);
});
```

This is what it prints out in the console

```
name { '["{\"title\":\"Trump ends self-made crisis\",\"pubDate\":\"2017-06-22 22:36:00\",\"link\":\"http://www.cnn.com/2017/06/22/politics/trump-comey-tapes-recordings-white-house/index.html\",\"guid\":\"http://www.cnn.com/2017/06/22/politics/trump-comey-tapes-recordings-white-house/index.html\",\"author\":\"\",\"thumbnail\":\"\",\"description\":\"President Donald Trump finally, grudgingly, had no choice but to come clean.\",\"content\":\"President Donald Trump finally, grudgingly, had no choice but to come clean.\",\"enclosure\":{\"link\":\"http://i2.cdn.turner.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/170622175804-trump-tweet-restricted-super-169.jpg\"},\"categories\":': [ '' ] }
name { '["{\"title\":\"Trump ends self-made crisis\",\"pubDate\":\"2017-06-22 22:36:00\",\"link\":\"http://www.cnn.com/2017/06/22/politics/trump-comey-tapes-recordings-white-house/index.html\",\"guid\":\"http://www.cnn.com/2017/06/22/politics/trump-comey-tapes-recordings-white-house/index.html\",\"author\":\"\",\"thumbnail\":\"\",\"description\":\"President Donald Trump finally, grudgingly, had no choice but to come clean.\",\"content\":\"President Donald Trump finally, grudgingly, had no choice but to come clean.\",\"enclosure\":{\"link\":\"http://i2.cdn.turner.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/170622175804-trump-tweet-restricted-super-169.jpg\"},\"categories\":': [ '' ] }
```

I want to extract the title value but for some reason I keep getting undefined when I try req.body.title.

Comment: Are you using body-parser at all in your node app?

Comment: As Peter Grainger correctly posts, you've got a bag of chips, and in the bag each chip is individually wrapped as well. You open the bag, take out a chip and bite - and there's just saran wrap taste... That's your `undefined`. Don't wrap stuff twice. Just make sure you have the bag (`JSON.stringify(info)`), but don't wrap individual chips (`JSON.stringify(value)` -> `value`). Also, don't do `replace` on `JSON.stringify` result - `JSON.stringify` is already as compact as possible, nothing good can come out of that.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are having an issue because you are using `JSON.stringify` on each array element and then using `JSON.stringify` on the compiled array.

You should get the expected outcome by stringifying the whole array without stringifying each part. i.e. in your case just stringify the `item`

```
              $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '/home',
                    data: JSON.stringify(item),
                    success: function (data) {


                    }
```

Comment: Almost. Due to bad indentation you can't see it but `item` is not available at that point in program. Do `info.push(item)` in the loop (without stringify), then stringify `info`.

Comment: Do you need to do the ```$.each``` loop if you are just sending the item array?  This will send loads of messages, one for each item in the array